# Wikibase install: Items do not show "add statement"

Tags: git, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation, wikibase

I have installed Wikibase on my custom Mediawiki, but when I look at an item, it does not show the "add statement" button under statements (In the picture this is the German "Aussagen"). However, I am pretty sure this button should be there in an out-of-the-box Wikibase install.

[image: Missing "add statement" button]

It did this in 1.39, so I updated to Mediawiki 1.41 and reinstalled all extensions for 1.41. The install according to [the instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation) seems to have gone without a hitch - Wikibase shows up as an installed extension, I can add items, and I can see all special Wikibase pages. The dependencies are up to date. Some of the maintenance scripts did funny things, see below. However, I do not think I need any interwiki things, since it is one Wiki and one Wikibase and that is it.

```
$ php maintenance/run.php ./extensions/Wikibase/lib/maintenance/populateSitesTable.php
Got no data from https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/api.php
done.
$ php maintenance/run.php ./extensions/Wikibase/repo/maintenance/rebuildItemsPerSite.php
Start rebuild...
Processed 23 entities.
Rebuild done.
$ php maintenance/run.php ./maintenance/populateInterwiki.php
Error during fetching data.
```

I also tried to update submodules, as this is also outlined in the [Wikibase Readme](https://doc.wikimedia.org/Wikibase/master/php/md_README.html), but I got these errors.

```
 $ git submodule update --init                                  
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: line 7: basename: command not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: line 7: sed: command not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 86: basename: command not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 86: sed: command not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 332: uname: command not found
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

On Special:Version, this is listed:
Software    Version
MediaWiki   1.41.0
PHP 8.2.15 (fpm-fcgi)
ICU 63.1
MySQL   5.7.42
Lua 5.1.5

Comment: So to clarify, you have a single wiki and enabled both the WikibaseRepo and WikibaseClient extensions there?

Comment: The problem persists whether I enable only the Repo or both the Client and the Repo.

Comment: That is, I had only the Repo enabled since I do not want to pull data from any other wikibase or wiki except mine. To try, I also enabled the client and reran the maintenance scripts. No change.